# Authorize domain calls

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a JS API that uses firebase internally for DB operations, API will be used on different website domains.
I need to restrict DB operations calls from authorized domains only.

I cannot restrict by UID as non signed user also need to access website.
I believe i need to figure out some way by anonymous user or else any better way, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restrict traffic to the Firebase Database to a specific domain or list of domains. Using Firebase Authentication is the only way to control access to your data.

Comment: Thanks Frank for reverting